# Template Path not getting in Live

Tags: magento-1.9, topmenu

I'm Following below method to display menu and it is working in my local but when i put it live the template path is not getting it's is showing like  `frontend/default/theme_name/template/` the page path is not getting.

You should override the _getHtml() method in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu class.

Here are the steps:

1.create your `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu/Custom.php`

2.put inside `class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Custom extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`

3.copy the `_getHtml() method from app/code/code/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` and customize it as needed

4.edit your `app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/layout/page.xml` and replace `<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/> with <block type="page/html_topmenu_custom" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue, set Compiler Status : Disabled

Go to `admin->System->Tools->Compilation.` Check if compilation is enabled, if enabled then disable it and clear the cache and run your compilation process